# How to enable Network ID in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, networking

My Windows XP won't let me change the workgroup name; the network ID
wizard is disabled as is the 'change' button under network ID. How I can enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Best bet is that you are not logged in as a user with administrative rights.

Comment: That makes we wonder, I don't ever recall anyone accidentally booting into a standard user in a workgroup. . .

Comment: I login with a administrator user

Comment: Can you verify that your user is part of the Administrators group?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound that your user is part of the Administrators group.

**HOW TO VERIFY IF YOU ARE AN ADMIN ON THE PC:**
Log on to windows 
Right click on your start menu
If you see "Open all users or Explor all users" 
means you have admin rights.